# how to test the number of parameters when logging/printf?

Tags: java

I'm using log4j for my application, but I'm afraid of having typed a wrong number of parameters in the log, like:

```
logger.info("%s %s %s", str1, str2);
logger.info("%s", str1, str2);
```

any ideas on some tool to help me figure out?

it doesn't seem too straight-forward to create a parser for that

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#VA_FORMAT_STRING_BAD_ARGUMENT). It has rules to check format strings, and compare the parameter types.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for logger, just for String.format()

Comment: @Lem0n I would suggest to raise a bug with Findbugs to get this added to Findbugs for Logger strings, or failing that, you can probably extend the inbuilt test to test against Logger yourself.